# Enum of type Unit

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, enums, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create an Enum or Sealed class that is gonna hold the values for a DropDownMenu in order to sort a list.

In my ViewModel I have

```
result.data.map { it.toPresentationModel() }.sortedWith(compareBy {it.date})
```

Instead of `compareBy {it.date})` I wanna do that inside the enum/sealed class because for other options I wanna do `(compareByDescending{it.date})` and just pass here the current selected value of the DropDownMenu.

And inside compareBy() I need to pass a parameter from a Data class

And also I would like to retrieve the enum's value name to put it inside my DropDownMenu

Here's how it looks like

[image]

Is this possible? Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your enum class can itself implement the Comparator interface so you can directly pass its instances to `compareBy` and other similar functions.

I don't think you should hard-code the names of the values, because it will make translations difficult. Put those names in String resources. You can perform a one-time initialization of the names once you have a Context available. You can override `toString()` to present this possibly translated name to make it easy to use this enum in drop-downs.

For example, given this class:

```
data class PresentationModel(val date: LocalDate, val price: BigInteger)
```

You could create this enum:

```
enum class PresentationSort(
    private val nameId: Int,
    compareBy: (PresentationModel)->Comparable<*>,
    isDescending: Boolean = false
): Comparator<PresentationModel> {
    Date(R.string.date, PresentationModel::date),
    DateDescending(R.string.date, PresentationModel::date, true),
    Price(R.string.price, PresentationModel::price);

    private var resourceName: String? = null
    private val comparator = if(isDescending) compareByDescending(compareBy) else compareBy(compareBy)
    override fun compare(o1: PresentationModel?, o2: PresentationModel?): Int 
        = comparator.compare(o1, o2)

    override fun toString() = resourceName ?: name

    companion object {
        fun initialize(context: Context) {
            for (value in values()) resourceName = context.getString(value.nameId)
        }
    }
 
}
```

And pass it like:

```
result.data.map { it.toPresentationModel() }.sortedWith(PresentationSort.Date)
```

`PresentationSort.initialize()` should be called at the earliest opportunity, like at the beginning of `onCreate()` of the MainActivity. This will also cause it to update to the latest translation if the user changed languages while your app is open.

Comment: This looks good but in `private val comparator = compareBy(compareBy)` I need to make this abstract so that for some values I use compareByDescending instead

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: I tried to do that after your first answer as it seemed logical but I'm getting this warning With old Native GC, variable in enum class can't be changed after initialization So I'm not sure it works, I'm testing in a bit

Comment: I ended up doing this instead 
`override fun compare(item1: PresentationModel, item2: PresentationModel): Int {
     return when (this) {
                Date -> item1.date.compareTo(item2.date)
                DescendingDate -> -item1.date.compareTo(item2.date)`
Your answer is cleaner but I can't get it to change the comparator variable, but thanks anyway it really helped :)  My formatting skills suck tho

Comment: I'm not sure what that was complaining about. I get no warnings or errors with the above code. The `comparator` property isn't being changed after initialization. After all, it's a `val`.

Comment: Hmm that's true, I tried it again and it doesn't show any warning now and is working,  very strange but it works, thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

You can implement functions inside of enums:

```
enum class SortBy(val name: String) {
    DATE("Date") {
        override fun <T : Comparable> sort(data: List<T>): List<T> { ... }
    },
    TIME("Time") {
        override fun <T : Comparable> sort(data: List<T>): List<T> { ... }
    },
    AMOUNT("Amount") {
        override fun <T : Comparable> sort(data: List<T>): List<T> { ... }
    },
    PRICE("Price") {
        override fun <T : Comparable> sort(data: List<T>): List<T> { ... }
    };

    abstract fun <T : Comparable> sort(data: List<T>): List<T>
}
```

Notice the semicolon after the last constant.

You can then implement it as an adapter or something.